# Extract data between 2 Uppercase block

Tags: python, regex

I have different long documents and I need to extract some data from it.

It may looks like

```
...

DESCRIPTION 

The present application relates to a semiconductor structure and a method of forming the same. More particularly, the present application relates to a semiconductor structure including a phase change memory (PCM) cell in which the resistance across the cell changes gradually. 

Phase change memory (PCM) is a type of non-volatile random access memory (NVRAM). A NVRAM retains its information when the power is turned off. This is in contrast to dynamic random access memory (DRAM) and static random access memory (SRAM), which both maintain data only for as long as power is applied. 

A typically PCM includes a material stack of, and from bottom to top, a bottom electrode, a phase change memory material that exhibits a change in atomic order (from crystalline to amorphous or vice versa), and a top electrode. In such PCMs, the resistance changes abruptly. For some applications such as, for example, analog computing or neuromorphic applications, it is desired to have the resistance of a PCM changing gradually (or at least multiple bits) instead of simply binary resistance states (i.e., high-low resistances). 

SUMMARY
```

It may be different phrases instead of `DESCRIPTION`, like `DESCRIPTION OF THE INVENTION`, `TECHNOLOGICAL DESCRIPTION`, `DESCRIPTION & CLAIMS`. And after that block it may be any other block but usually it starts from uppercase phrase.

I try to extract a text between these two parts with

```
re.search(r'DESCRIPTION\s+(.*)\s+'
```

and it works but just for one paragraph and only for `DESCRIPTION` in the name of block.

I tried

```
re.search(r'DESCRIPTION[\s&A-Z]+(.*)\s+[A-Z]+')
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Probably, something like `(?s)\b(?:DESCRIPTION(?: OF THE INVENTION| & CLAIMS)?|TECHNOLOGICAL DESCRIPTION)\b(.*?)\nSUMMARY\b` will do. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mnq9fG/2).

Comment: Or match all following lines that do not start with 2 or more uppercase chars `^DESCRIPTION .*((?:\n(?![A-Z]{2,}(?!\S)).*)*) ` https://regex101.com/r/gkIs55/1

Comment: You may use this regex: [`^.*\bDESCRIPTION\b.*\n*((?:.*\n)+?)(?=^[A-Z]{2,}\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/3pjk7l/2/)

Comment: @anubhava your decision doesn't work on the example in the question

Comment: I have provided demo link as well in my 2nd comment. It is working as described and returning 2 matches on sample text.

Comment: If there is not always a space after DESCRIPTION, you could also allow only the characters from the character class and make use of word boundaries like already suggested in the other comments `^DESCRIPTION\b[ &A-Z]*((?:\n(?![A-Z]{2,}\b).*)*)` https://regex101.com/r/xahR2D/1

Comment: @ldevyataykina Did any of the answers or comments work out?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
\b(?:DESCRIPTION|DESCRIPTION OF THE INVENTION|DESCRIPTION & CLAIMS|TECHNOLOGICAL DESCRIPTION)\b([\w\W]*?)\nSUMMARY\b
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/y0TGtA/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DESCRIPTION              'DESCRIPTION'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DESCRIPTION OF THE       'DESCRIPTION OF THE INVENTION'
    INVENTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DESCRIPTION &            'DESCRIPTION & CLAIMS'
    CLAIMS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TECHNOLOGICAL            'TECHNOLOGICAL DESCRIPTION'
    DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w\W]*?                 any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), non-word characters (all
                             but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SUMMARY                  'SUMMARY'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##nVRda9swFH3Pr7j0YdgjNYy9FUYJaboGmrS0WcdYxrixb2IxWTKS3DTQ/54dKUkbOvqykBAjXd3zcY/VbkJtzeftVjWtdYGc9HpOVvJEX8idzBfZ@dnF6H54N76djW@mz0fPdHNJs6sRjacPo@k/mx9oeD0YT@6fZ6Ph1fTm@ubreDi4pqOSHM1/ztfz778@nudzc/9tMhnc/ZgvTnq9ID789sGBw8lx07mZm1kt1DrxYgJx22pVclDWgLhmnKNgiclLo0prqq4M1hE64aFzQmwq7DYCzRXZJS2ta5RZUUBTz40UNLEoa9kFVXaand700@Z/IypT6q6KGExtzV6orNmsBCQa6zaU3Q4nOZWiNUppXauyToDAUz6wKUG6dNb7tJrqdg08rRxXHWu9KZIxt@92Vx7gYdNKlGysOX20YK40UGCIbYBQChAOh6YPd4NJXtCA0hO4BFbGkwr4mejZzoB1LWbnjl2LizCQbCQ6uyxoVmMhfg3BmODYh2hVtTEMq96BvojIaUwQH94tu49l/b1dCxtqasAwsqSKA5M1ehOHS@xJ22i@fyWZZijVzrVBNAYThY0Es/bzkugYVIpTrCOV8g9E9ROxpQMfYAb8QU@wLdYPC6KlDM5W0n9n3i9NQ82B5KlWi2grH8qggNEIyq2rwDdLcKXbgITWykiKG1q1te08iuhRISOP4jzn/X3AwemVSUFjQ76DUdDn@2/TdUgTL1zXhhimyxhg28hx2P2uA@N8tFWeuGl1FGlY2xUG3LRdiCnHppEOnCNDqDju0UeC4gBgr3KICZTU/ChvGSGknGaRqMWmL0mnLM40kJaYpqbTQYEGRQsRc@ODcHqvPW4zVC@UYXh@1DumCmIzVUjRp1qt6lNt10cVPt/lYn8d4TLCxKAct6EUXtiVdZbuRxi5v6XyXk8tKZWd9Qif1iGLWVooVs52bfYpL1Co2izPe9vtXw)**:

```py
import re

regex = r"\b(?:DESCRIPTION|DESCRIPTION OF THE INVENTION|DESCRIPTION & CLAIMS|TECHNOLOGICAL DESCRIPTION)\b([\w\W]*?)\nSUMMARY\b"

test_str = "DESCRIPTION \n\nThe present application relates to a semiconductor structure and a method of forming the same. More particularly, the present application relates to a semiconductor structure including a phase change memory (PCM) cell in which the resistance across the cell changes gradually. \n\nPhase change memory (PCM) is a type of non-volatile random access memory (NVRAM). A NVRAM retains its information when the power is turned off. This is in contrast to dynamic random access memory (DRAM) and static random access memory (SRAM), which both maintain data only for as long as power is applied. \n\nA typically PCM includes a material stack of, and from bottom to top, a bottom electrode, a phase change memory material that exhibits a change in atomic order (from crystalline to amorphous or vice versa), and a top electrode. In such PCMs, the resistance changes abruptly. For some applications such as, for example, analog computing or neuromorphic applications, it is desired to have the resistance of a PCM changing gradually (or at least multiple bits) instead of simply binary resistance states (i.e., high-low resistances). \n\nSUMMARY"

match = re.search(regex, test_str)

if match:
    print(match.group(1).strip())
```

**Results**:

```
The present application relates to a semiconductor structure and a method of forming the same. More particularly, the present application relates to a semiconductor structure including a phase change memory (PCM) cell in which the resistance across the cell changes gradually. 

Phase change memory (PCM) is a type of non-volatile random access memory (NVRAM). A NVRAM retains its information when the power is turned off. This is in contrast to dynamic random access memory (DRAM) and static random access memory (SRAM), which both maintain data only for as long as power is applied. 

A typically PCM includes a material stack of, and from bottom to top, a bottom electrode, a phase change memory material that exhibits a change in atomic order (from crystalline to amorphous or vice versa), and a top electrode. In such PCMs, the resistance changes abruptly. For some applications such as, for example, analog computing or neuromorphic applications, it is desired to have the resistance of a PCM changing gradually (or at least multiple bits) instead of simply binary resistance states (i.e., high-low resistances).
```

Answer (score 0):

Several noteworthy points:

`(.*)` does not match newlines, use `((.|\n|\r)*)` instead.

Blocks are separated by uppercase phrases that can be expressed as `\r?\n[A-Z& ]+\r?\n`. But the first phrase may be preceded not by a newline but by the beginning of the entire text (`^`).

Each block to be matched must come after such a phrase (the lookbehind operator `?<=`) and it must end with the end of the entire text (`$`) or before the next phrase (the lookahead operator `?=`).

The `((.|\n|\r)*)` is "greedy" and would match several blocks including the intervening phrases. In order to avoid that, make it "reluctant" by using `*?` instead of `*`.

All in all, this leads to the regular expression

```
(?<=(^|\r?\n)[A-Z& ]+\r?\n)((.|\n|\r)*?)(?=$|\r?\n[A-Z& ]+\r?\n)
```

Comment: I would suggest either using an inline modifier `(?s)` to have to dot match a newline `.*?`, or use `[\s\S]*?` instead of using an alternation `(.|\n|\r)*?` as that would not be so efficient going through the alternatives for every character.

Comment: Useful comment: I didn't know about this modifier before. But I cannot (yet) vote on your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could try something similar to this: `(^[A-Z &]+$)((?:.(?!^[A-Z &]+$))*)` in combination with the re.MULTILINE and re.DOTALL flags.

`^[A-Z &]+$` serves to detect a title: a line with only upper case letters (plus   and `&`). hence, in the pattern above

- `(^[A-Z &]+$)`: captures the title of a section, while...
- `((?:.(?!^[A-Z &]+$))*)`: ...captures the body that follows the title, that is any sequence of characters under the condition that a character must not be followed by a line that looks like a title (the negative lookahead `(?!^[A-Z &]+$)`)

code:

```
import re

text = """

DESCRIPTION  

The present application relates to a semiconductor structure and a method of forming the same. More particularly, the present application relates to a semiconductor structure including a phase change memory (PCM) cell in which the resistance across the cell changes gradually. 

Phase change memory (PCM) is a type of non-volatile random access memory (NVRAM). A NVRAM retains its information when the power is turned off. This is in contrast to dynamic random access memory (DRAM) and static random access memory (SRAM), which both maintain data only for as long as power is applied. 

A typically PCM includes a material stack of, and from bottom to top, a bottom electrode, a phase change memory material that exhibits a change in atomic order (from crystalline to amorphous or vice versa), and a top electrode. In such PCMs, the resistance changes abruptly. For some applications such as, for example, analog computing or neuromorphic applications, it is desired to have the resistance of a PCM changing gradually (or at least multiple bits) instead of simply binary resistance states (i.e., high-low resistances). 

  ABRA & CADABRA

...magic happening here....

SUMMARY

sfsdfsdf abc def
* one
* two
* three

sdfdsf

ABC
"""

for m in re.finditer(r"(^[A-Z &]+$)((?:.(?!^[A-Z &]+$))*)", text, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL):
    print((m.group(1).strip(), m.group(2).strip()))
```

output:

```
('DESCRIPTION  GGG', 'The present application relates to a semiconductor structure and a method of forming the same. More particularly, the present application relates to a semiconductor structure including a phase change memory (PCM) cell in which the resistance across the cell changes gradually. \n\nPhase change memory (PCM) is a type of non-volatile random access memory (NVRAM). A NVRAM retains its information when the power is turned off. This is in contrast to dynamic random access memory (DRAM) and static random access memory (SRAM), which both maintain data only for as long as power is applied. \n\nA typically PCM includes a material stack of, and from bottom to top, a bottom electrode, a phase change memory material that exhibits a change in atomic order (from crystalline to amorphous or vice versa), and a top electrode. In such PCMs, the resistance changes abruptly. For some applications such as, for example, analog computing or neuromorphic applications, it is desired to have the resistance of a PCM changing gradually (or at least multiple bits) instead of simply binary resistance states (i.e., high-low resistances).')
('ABRA & CADABRA', '...magic happening here....')
('SUMMARY', 'sfsdfsdf abc def\n* one\n* two\n* three\n\nsdfdsf')
('ABC', 'sfsfd')
```

...you might have to extend the character class `[A-Z &]` with additional characters (e.g. ndash, mdash or similar?) depending on the content of your input...